# Calculating quantities

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have the question "Calculate the following quantities giving your answer to an appropriate number of significant figures:

$$V \quad \text {given}\quad U = -1.82 \frac ms \quad a = 0.34 \frac m{s^2}\quad s = 120.44 m$$

And $$V^2=U^2+2as$$

By putting all the values in I get the final answer of $$V = 9.231 \frac {m^2}{s^2}$$

Could you tell me if the units for the answer as well as the value is correct and if not could you point out where I went wrong.

Comment: Your numerical answer is perfect. The units are (effecitvely) the square root of the square of the units of velocity, so, $(m^2 s^{-2})^{\frac{1}{2}}=ms^{-1}$

Comment: Have you learned about error propagation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Bacon said, when you take square roots, you need to apply that to the units also.  But another issue is that since all your numbers have only 2 significant digits, your answer can not have 3 significant digits.  You need to round to at least $9.23.$ and maybe to $9.2$, depending on the opinions and mood of the grader.  (Sometimes multiplication causes the loss of significant digits.)